# Bower not taking the latest version

Tags: bower

In my project I have created some bower components, which I am using in my bower.json file of main app like below.

```
"My-Component": "1.0.12"
```

It was working fine too. Now i created a newer version of My-Component and updated the bower.json file like below.

```
"My-Component": "1.0.13"
```

When i do bower install the new version is not getting installed.Its referring to the old one.

Comment: What is the response of the command : `bower info My-Component` ? Post the result please

Comment: Its showing the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax for your dependency in you bower.json of your main app:

```
"My-Component": "~1.0.12"
```

> this mean "at least that version, but not greater than 2.x"

If all is done as it should be, maybe you simply need to clear bower cache:

```
bower cache clean
```

then re-install:

```
bower install
```

If not, there is something wrong with your component.

Maybe you missed to tag the new version of your component:

```
cd ~/My-Component/
git tag v1.0.13
git push upstream
git push --tags
```

Then update your main app:

```
cd ~/MyApp/
bower install My-Component --save
```

Comment: I cannot clean the cache as it will run on a build machine once i commit the code and cause issues there. I have tried the ~, but its not working.